# Is there any .pas file (Delphi or Pascal) parser?

Tags: delphi, parsing

I need to parse Delphi .pas files to work with classes with read/write ability. Adding/Modifying/Deleting fields, properties, methods etc. Any idea how to implement this? The implementation is not necessarily in Delphi, scripting languages ​​are also allowed.

Comment: Did you try a websearch for delphi parser and pascal parser?

Comment: yeah, but still found only xml parsers written on Delphi.

Comment: Not sure if this is what could help you: **Castalia Lexer and Parser**

Comment: I think you have two mixed questions here: "is there any .pas file parser" in the subject and "any idea how to implement this" in the message. Which is it? For the subject, Castalia should help. For the implementation ideas, it should be done as with any language parser - I would suggest starting with the grammar analysis...

Comment: @Andrey You need to use a better search engine. Google returns Castalia parser as the first hit and that's what you need here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sure! But russian version of google hasnt that link on top page, strange..

Comment: It does when I go to google.ru: http://www.google.ru/#hl=en&q=delphi+parser

Comment: Soon it might point to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the [Castalia Delphi Parser](https://github.com/jacobthurman/Castalia-Delphi-Parser) by Jacob Thurman currently hosted on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

CnWizards have built-in syntax highlighter so they use some parser too, but I do not remember which exactly. You can look into their sources at https://github.com/cnpack/cnwizards

Answer (score 1):

[PasParse](https://github.com/Turbo87/PasParse) is good for you ! Delphi port of the excellent (C#) [DGrok](http://dgrok.excastle.com/).

Delphi 2007 level.